# Keybindings in Unity

Tags: unity, software-engineering, keyboard

I need to know how to bind keys to actions through Javascript within Unity.

When I develop web applications, I normally use this:

```
var KeyBind = function() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyUpHandler, false);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", function() {
            keyDownHandler(window.event);
        });
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", function() {
            keyUpHandler(window.event);
        });
    }

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key == "27") {
            window.location="file:///D:/Users/pferris/Documents/Unnamed%20Site%202/HordeAttack.html";            
        };
};
```

Does Unity use a similar method, or will I have to do something completely different?

I've been through the help section a bit, but nothing seemed very satisfactory.

Comment: This is less urgent but it would be nice if people could tell me how best to deal with the workflow of our company (Me and my friends are developing a game) since the lead programmer can't be persuaded to do anything. I'm the lead artist, so this sort of thing is waaaaaaaay beyond what I would normally do.

Answer (score 2):

A similar method would be from the Input class

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

```
function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
        print ("space key was pressed");
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with where this goes? I tried placing it in scripts for some of my assets (terrain and a camera), but nothing happened when I tested it.

Comment: @PaulFerris it needs to go in an Update or FixedUpdate method on some object so that it gets called every frame.

Comment: I did that, though. It's running from within an Update method, but nothing is displayed in the console when I test it.